# 32 Bit ApiKey/AppId?

Tags: facebook, api-key

How are people getting a 32 bit apiKey/AppId on Facebook apps? I notice this when users are using the JSDK and I view their source. I can't seem to figure out how their getting it. My keys are short (apart from secret).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your app old? the longer IDs only came into being some time in 2010 I believe, i'm also not sure how this affects your app, why do you need a longer app id?